# Scrolling not working after UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app scrolview is made active using the following code.

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 760);
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

[scroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scroll.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scroll.clipsToBounds = YES;
scroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
scroll.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
[scroll setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

But after using the UIImagePicker/controller.ie. after selecting the image from the phone gallery,scrolling is not working. The above code is written in the viewWillAppear section.Can anyone help me so that I can make scrolling working even after the UIImagePickerController? Thanks for any help ...

Comment: how do you dismiss the UIImagePickerController? can you post the dismiss line please.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue lately. Mine was in having a ViewControllerA which was a parent to ViewControllerB which in turn is a parent of ViewControllerC1..N. ViewControllerB has a scrollview which scrolls views of ViewControllerC1..N. It is reproducible only on iOS9.

If I present UIImagePickerController to get images from gallery (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) from ViewControllerA after dismissing it scrollview of ViewControllerB stops scrolling correctly.

I have made a workaround. I push dummy view controller into navigation stack, then present image picker and then pop back to ViewControllerA.
This way it works.

It seems like in iOS9 UIImagePickerController messes up something with touch events in its presenting view controller.

Answer (score -1):

replace your dismissing code like this and check:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 760);
        [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

        [scroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
        scroll.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
        scroll.clipsToBounds = YES;
        scroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
        scroll.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
        [scroll setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    }];
```